# Prometheus alert when a specific endpoint responds with http 4xx code

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to create an alert with Prometheus to when a specific endpoint responds with an error code.
Basicly I want an alert to be fired everytime my endpoint returns 4xx or 5xx http codes.

I'm running locally a docker container with grafana, prometheus and alert manager but can't find a way to create this alert. I'm also running my API locally and tried to create a test alert with expr: up == 1 and it never fires the alert, it looks like my API is unreachable?

this is my prometheus.yml

```html
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Load and evaluate rules in this file every 'evaluation_interval' seconds.
rule_files:
  - 'alert.rules'
  # - "first.rus"
  # - "second.rules"

# alert
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - scheme: http
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - "alertmanager:9093"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'my-api'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: '/api/users'
    params:
      module: [http_4xx]
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['127.0.0.1:8081']
```

and my alert.rules

```html
groups:
- name: example
  rules:
  - alert: test
    expr: up == 1
    for: 10s
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: "Site up: {{$labels.instance}}"
      description: "Site Up: {{$labels.instance}} for more than 30 seconds"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you have is your api service and an instance of Prometheus. If this is in fact the case, you cannot check codes that are returned.

To do this, you need blackbox_exporter, that will probe your api through http module. You can find how to install and configure it [here](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter).

Once blackbox is up and running, and Prometheus scrapes probe results from it, you can use query like `probe_http_status_code >= 400` to get probes that returned code more than or equal 400. (Or `probe_http_status_code{instance="localhost:8081"} >= 400` for a single service).

This query can be used in `alerts.yml` in the following manner:

```yaml
  - alert: ProbeFailed
    expr: probe_http_status_code >= 400
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: Probe of api failed. Returned code: {{ $value }}
```

---

To fire alert only in case of 4xx code, and not 5xx, use expression `probe_http_status_code >= 400 < 500` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by

```
- alert: Https code not 200
    expr:probe_http_status_code{instance="<api>", job="<job-name>"} != 200
```

It will fire up if you get anything other than 200 status code.

Comment: Why should alert be fired when probe returns 3xx? While it's of course better to probe target directly, I don't see need for alert in that case.

Comment: That works in my case, I also use `or` in some cases. Totally depends on your usecase.